# combine column and splines highcharts using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

I can generate now highcharts calling data with mysql. Now I plot splines, but I need to combine 2 splines (for TMax and TMin) and 1 column (for Rain). Anybody knows what I should change in the next two files, I guess in index.php ? I can do plot this combination using csv files but now with mysql. Any idea?

Code of mysql-highcharts.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect("xxxx","xxx","xxx","xxx");
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');
function split($date){
$day=substr($date,0,2);
$month=substr($date,3,2);
$year=substr($date,6,4);
return $year . "/" . $month . "/" . $day;
}
$sth = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT City,TMax FROM Meteo2 where City= '" . $_SESSION["City"] ."' AND Data BETWEEN '" . split($_SESSION["date8"]) ."' AND '" . split($_SESSION["date9"]) ."'order by Data");

$rows = array();
$rows['name'] = 'TMAX';
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($sth)) {
$rows['data'][] = $r['TMax'];
}

$sth = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT City,TMin FROM Meteo2 where City= '" . $_SESSION["City"] ."' AND Data BETWEEN '" . split($_SESSION["date8"]) ."' AND '" . split($_SESSION["date9"]) ."'order by Data");

$rows1 = array();
$rows1['name'] = 'TMIN';
while($rr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
$rows1['data'][] = $rr['TMin'];
}

$sth = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT City,Rain FROM Meteo2 where City= '" . $_SESSION["City"] ."' AND Data BETWEEN '" . split($_SESSION["date8"]) ."' AND '" . split($_SESSION["date9"]) ."'order by Data");

$rows2 = array();
$rows2['name'] = 'RAINS';
while($rr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
$rows2['data'][] = $rr['Rain'];
}

$result = array();
array_push($result,$rows);
array_push($result,$rows1);
array_push($result,$rows2);

print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Code of index.php (highcharts code)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Highcharts Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
$city = $_POST["City"];
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['City'] = $_POST['City'];
$_SESSION['date8'] = $_POST['date8'];
$_SESSION['date9'] = $_POST['date9'];
?>


$(function () {
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
$.getJSON("mysql-highcharts.php", function(json) {
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
renderTo: 'container',
type: 'spline',
marginRight: 130,
marginBottom: 25
},
title: {
text: 'TMax-TMin-Rain <?php echo $city ?>',
x: -20 //center
},
subtitle: {
text: '',
x: -20
},
xAxis: {
categories: []
},
yAxis: {
title: {
text: 'Temperature (ºC)'
},
plotLines: [{
value: 0,
width: 1,
color: '#808080'
}]
},
tooltip: {
formatter: function() {
return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
this.x +': '+ this.y;
}
},
legend: {
layout: 'vertical',
align: 'right',
verticalAlign: 'top',
x: -10,
y: 100,
borderWidth: 0
},
series: json
});
});
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i would suggest you to check sql joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set for that specific series type, like this:

```
$rows1 = array();
$rows1['name'] = 'TMIN';
$rows1['type'] = 'column';
while($rr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows1['data'][] = $rr['TMin'];
}
```